# Subsurface Modifier Principle

Tags: modifiers

Just a swift question I have. When doing a hard surface modelling, is the Subsurface modifier off limits, and its more recommended to use Bevel modifier? becuase Subsurface modifier is for smoother topology such as, character design?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are no rules.
>   Use what works for *you* :).

---

Sometimes *bevel* doesn't give good results, so *subdivision* needs to be used instead.
They can also be used together for easier cotrol.

*Bevel modifier* - easily adjustable edges, limited in tight corners (creates overlapping geometry)
*Subdivision Modifier* - works almost anywhere because it actually *moves* the geometry.

*Using Bevel and Subdivision together*

[image]

Comment: Point Taken, Thanks for your demonstration.